# reactJS - How to concatenate within props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to add a span class next to the price of 25 in the below description props. Is there a way I can correctly add in a span there. Currently getting [object Object] when running the below code.

```
  <Pricing
    title="Standard"
    description={<span>"$"</span> + "25"}
    button="Buy Now for $25" 
    amount={2500}
  />
```

Comment: This totally depends on `Pricing`. Is it your component? Please, post it, it's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<span>"$"</span>` results in React component that will be stringified `[object Object]` when concatenated with a string.

Given that `Pricing` renders `description` prop as

```
{prop.description}
```

`description` prop can be provided with any valid JSX expression. E.g. an array:

```
  <Pricing
    title="Standard"
    description={[<span>"$"</span>, "25"]}
    button="Buy Now for $25" 
    amount={2500}
  />
```

Or `React.Fragment`:

```
  <Pricing
    title="Standard"
    description={<><span>"$"</span>25</>}
    button="Buy Now for $25" 
    amount={2500}
  />
```